# jquery chosen not selected on web load

Tags: jquery, onload, ready

using jQuery chosen plugin, encountered a problem - chosen can not triggered or selected in document.ready or window.load event.

Here is the problem code:

```
$(function() {
    $("select").chosen();
});
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#select_chosen').val("104").trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

or I move the trigger to document.ready is the same:

```
$(function(){
    $(select).chosen();
    $('#select_chosen').val("104").trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

All I confused is why chosen object can not act right after DOM and chosen plugin loaded.
If there is someone can answer, I would really appreciate, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you meant `$('#select_chosen').chosen()`? AFAIK `select` is not defined. If it is, we need to see the definition. Your relevant HTML might also help here.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$("select").chosen();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You should use same jQuery Object for initializing 'chosen' on it and then triggering 'chosen:update' OR change event. Below code snippet should work on document load: 
// initialize
$("#select_chosen").chosen();
// change value
$("#select_chosen").val("104");
// trigger change event
$("#select_chosen").change();
// trigger 'chosen:updated' event
$("#select_chosen").trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: Adding `.change()` helped!

Comment: Sequence is perfect! Thanks Ashish

Answer (score 0):

It might be help you.

```
var selectId = $(this).data('id');

$('#inputId').chosen().val(selectId).change().trigger('chosen:updated');
```